# UPDATING AN XML Tag Value

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xpath, xquery

Here is my sample script. What I want to do is to update tags intstatusID And strStatus of xml variable @xmlPlan that satisfy join condition

```
Declare @xmlPlan xml = N'<planBean>
    <intPlanID>1</intPlanID>
    <intStatusID>2</intStatusID>
    <strPlanStatus>Published</strPlanStatus>
    <strName>1 Loyalty Programs Plan</strName>
    <supplierGroupsList>
      <supplierGroup>
        <intPlanSupplierGroupID>1</intPlanSupplierGroupID>
        <intPlanID>1</intPlanID>
        <strName>Supplier Group 1</strName>
        <intStatusID>8</intStatusID>
        <strStatus>New</strStatus>
        <copySGAction>Enabled</copySGAction>
        <editSGAction>Enabled</editSGAction>
        <deleteSGAction>Enabled</deleteSGAction>
        <intActionId>5</intActionId>
        <supplierList>
          <supplier>
            <strName>HJK *</strName>
            <strSourceSupplierID>0XX135</strSourceSupplierID>
            <intStatusID>13</intStatusID>
            <strStatus>New</strStatus>
            <dtStartDate>
              <maxDate>20160101</maxDate>
              <minDate>20160101</minDate>
              <orgDate>20160101</orgDate>
            </dtStartDate>
            <dtEndDate>
              <maxDate>20161231</maxDate>
              <minDate>20161231</minDate>
              <orgDate>20161231</orgDate>
            </dtEndDate>
          </supplier>
          <supplier>
            <strName>KGH LABORATORIES LTD</strName>
            <strSourceSupplierID>0XX136</strSourceSupplierID>
            <intStatusID>13</intStatusID>
            <strStatus>New</strStatus>
            <dtStartDate>
              <maxDate>20160101</maxDate>
              <minDate>20160101</minDate>
              <orgDate>20160101</orgDate>
            </dtStartDate>
            <dtEndDate>
              <maxDate>20161231</maxDate>
              <minDate>20161231</minDate>
              <orgDate>20161231</orgDate>
            </dtEndDate>
          </supplier>        
        </supplierList>
      </supplierGroup>
      <supplierGroup>
        <intPlanSupplierGroupID>2</intPlanSupplierGroupID>
        <intPlanID>1</intPlanID>
        <strName>Supplier Group 2</strName>
        <intStatusID>8</intStatusID>
        <strStatus>New</strStatus>
        <copySGAction>Enabled</copySGAction>
        <editSGAction>Enabled</editSGAction>
        <deleteSGAction>Disabled</deleteSGAction>
        <intActionId>5</intActionId>
        <supplierList>
          <supplier>            
            <strName>ABC FOODSERVICE *</strName>
            <strSourceSupplierID>0XX134</strSourceSupplierID>
            <intStatusID>13</intStatusID>
            <strStatus>New</strStatus>
            <dtStartDate>
              <maxDate>20160101</maxDate>
              <minDate>20160101</minDate>
              <orgDate>20160101</orgDate>
            </dtStartDate>
            <dtEndDate>
              <maxDate>20161231</maxDate>
              <minDate>20161231</minDate>
              <orgDate>20161231</orgDate>
            </dtEndDate>            
          </supplier>         
        </supplierList>
      </supplierGroup>
      <supplierGroup>
        <intPlanSupplierGroupID>3</intPlanSupplierGroupID>
        <intPlanID>1</intPlanID>
        <strName>Supplier Group 3</strName>
        <intStatusID>8</intStatusID>
        <strStatus>New</strStatus>
        <copySGAction>Enabled</copySGAction>
        <editSGAction>Enabled</editSGAction>
        <deleteSGAction>Disabled</deleteSGAction>
        <intActionId>5</intActionId>
        <supplierList>
          <supplier>            
            <strName>XZ FOODSERVICE *</strName>
            <strSourceSupplierID>0XX133</strSourceSupplierID>
            <intStatusID>13</intStatusID>
            <strStatus>New</strStatus>
            <dtStartDate>
              <maxDate>20160101</maxDate>
              <minDate>20160101</minDate>
              <orgDate>20160101</orgDate>
            </dtStartDate>
            <dtEndDate>
              <maxDate>20161231</maxDate>
              <minDate>20161231</minDate>
              <orgDate>20161231</orgDate>
            </dtEndDate>            
          </supplier>         
        </supplierList>
      </supplierGroup>
    </supplierGroupsList>    
  </planBean>'

Create Table #SupplierGroups (strName varchar(500), intStatus int, strStatus varchar(200) )

Insert Into #SupplierGroups (strName, intStatus, strStatus) Values 
('Supplier Group 1', 10, 'Active'), ('Supplier Group 3', 10, 'Active')

SELECT a.*, t.c.value('(strName/text())[1]', 'varchar(500)') FROM 
@xmlPlan.nodes('planBean/supplierGroupsList/supplierGroup') t(c)
Inner Join #SupplierGroups a ON a.strName = t.c.value('(strName/text())[1]', 'varchar(500)')
```

**-- I want XML tags intStatusID AND strStatus
-- To be updated as [[intStatusID 10 /intStatusID, strStatus Active /strStatus]] of "Supplier Group 1" And "Supplier Group 3" only
-- I want @xmlPlan variable like below**

```
/*
<planBean>
    <intPlanID>1</intPlanID>
    <intStatusID>2</intStatusID>
    <strPlanStatus>Published</strPlanStatus>
    <strName>1 Loyalty Programs Plan</strName>
    <supplierGroupsList>
      <supplierGroup>
        <intPlanSupplierGroupID>1</intPlanSupplierGroupID>
        <intPlanID>1</intPlanID>
        <strName>Supplier Group 1</strName>
        <intStatusID>10</intStatusID>
        <strStatus>Active</strStatus>
        <copySGAction>Enabled</copySGAction>
        <editSGAction>Enabled</editSGAction>
        <deleteSGAction>Enabled</deleteSGAction>
        <intActionId>5</intActionId>
        <supplierList>
          <supplier>
            <strName>HJK *</strName>
            <strSourceSupplierID>0XX135</strSourceSupplierID>
            <intStatusID>13</intStatusID>
            <strStatus>New</strStatus>
            <dtStartDate>
              <maxDate>20160101</maxDate>
              <minDate>20160101</minDate>
              <orgDate>20160101</orgDate>
            </dtStartDate>
            <dtEndDate>
              <maxDate>20161231</maxDate>
              <minDate>20161231</minDate>
              <orgDate>20161231</orgDate>
            </dtEndDate>
          </supplier>
          <supplier>
            <strName>KGH LABORATORIES LTD</strName>
            <strSourceSupplierID>0XX136</strSourceSupplierID>
            <intStatusID>13</intStatusID>
            <strStatus>New</strStatus>
            <dtStartDate>
              <maxDate>20160101</maxDate>
              <minDate>20160101</minDate>
              <orgDate>20160101</orgDate>
            </dtStartDate>
            <dtEndDate>
              <maxDate>20161231</maxDate>
              <minDate>20161231</minDate>
              <orgDate>20161231</orgDate>
            </dtEndDate>
          </supplier>        
        </supplierList>
      </supplierGroup>
      <supplierGroup>
        <intPlanSupplierGroupID>2</intPlanSupplierGroupID>
        <intPlanID>1</intPlanID>
        <strName>Supplier Group 2</strName>
        <intStatusID>8</intStatusID>
        <strStatus>New</strStatus>
        <copySGAction>Enabled</copySGAction>
        <editSGAction>Enabled</editSGAction>
        <deleteSGAction>Disabled</deleteSGAction>
        <intActionId>5</intActionId>
        <supplierList>
          <supplier>            
            <strName>ABC FOODSERVICE *</strName>
            <strSourceSupplierID>0XX134</strSourceSupplierID>
            <intStatusID>13</intStatusID>
            <strStatus>New</strStatus>
            <dtStartDate>
              <maxDate>20160101</maxDate>
              <minDate>20160101</minDate>
              <orgDate>20160101</orgDate>
            </dtStartDate>
            <dtEndDate>
              <maxDate>20161231</maxDate>
              <minDate>20161231</minDate>
              <orgDate>20161231</orgDate>
            </dtEndDate>            
          </supplier>         
        </supplierList>
      </supplierGroup>
      <supplierGroup>
        <intPlanSupplierGroupID>3</intPlanSupplierGroupID>
        <intPlanID>1</intPlanID>
        <strName>Supplier Group 3</strName>
        <intStatusID>10</intStatusID>
        <strStatus>Active</strStatus>
        <copySGAction>Enabled</copySGAction>
        <editSGAction>Enabled</editSGAction>
        <deleteSGAction>Disabled</deleteSGAction>
        <intActionId>5</intActionId>
        <supplierList>
          <supplier>            
            <strName>XZ FOODSERVICE *</strName>
            <strSourceSupplierID>0XX133</strSourceSupplierID>
            <intStatusID>13</intStatusID>
            <strStatus>New</strStatus>
            <dtStartDate>
              <maxDate>20160101</maxDate>
              <minDate>20160101</minDate>
              <orgDate>20160101</orgDate>
            </dtStartDate>
            <dtEndDate>
              <maxDate>20161231</maxDate>
              <minDate>20161231</minDate>
              <orgDate>20161231</orgDate>
            </dtEndDate>            
          </supplier>         
        </supplierList>
      </supplierGroup>
    </supplierGroupsList>    
  </planBean>
*/
```

Comment: What in the XML do you want to modify? Is this **exactly one change** or might there be several actions? In general: the XML method `.modify()` is very limited... But there are *work-arounds*... You must provide more information... Please try to set up a minimal but fully working test example with existing XML, table data and expected output.

Comment: I have updated details